After moving Keycloak from one Server to another - Login Problems
We have a Web Application which is using Keycloak as a login-provider.
We had to move keycloak from one Linux V-Server to another. The domain we are using is exactly the same (i just set the A-Record to the new servers ip).
The Webapplication redirects to the keycloak and both sites are running SSL fine.
I can login to the keycloak admin-console and can manage all users etc.
When loging in to the Web App, it redirects and i can login.
BUT after the login we are working with some Data from the Keycloak Users (attibutes) and this wont work...
Before we moved to the other Server everything was fine.
Now i get errors like this:
2024-06-05 15:19:28.5032|2|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer|Connection ID "8718968884494910709", Request ID "8000c543-0001-7900-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

Do i have to update some keys inside keycloak to get it working again? I have no clue... I switched back to the old server we used before and everything runs fine...
